# working with files, iterators, strings, and string formatting in Python

Tags: python

I am working with texts from Project Gutenberg which is an online library of eBooks that includes a lot of literature for which U.S. copyright has expired. In this assignment, you will process these files, count vowels and consonants, and convert some of the text. We will use not only English texts but those from other languages to demonstrate the benefits of Unicode encoding. A template notebook is provided with a cell to help download the files given a URL. You will read this data, do some calculations, and write a new output file in a similar format. We will be working with three books, but write your code so that it can be adapted to work with other texts as well. The three texts are:
Pride and Prejudice, J. Austen. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-0.txt
Du côté de chez Swann, M. Proust. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2650/2650-0.txt
Sense and Sensibility, J. Austen. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/161/161-0.txt

Question:
I am expected to write a function that gives the filename, opens the local file and reads the downloaded file, returning the processed lines as a list. Project Gutenberg includes metadata at the beginning of the text and license information at the end of the text. The actual text is contained between the lines
*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK  ***
and
*** END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK  ***
where  is the name of the book. Read (and
discard) lines until you hit the START tag. Then, read all the lines up to but not
including the END tag in a list of strings. Remove any leading and trailing whitespace from the lines. You will need to figure out how to
find the START and END tags and which lines should be included.

***strip will be useful to remove whitespace.
Answer:

```
def process_file (filename):
    """ opens a file and passes back a list of its words"""
    h = dict()
    fin = open(filename)

    for line in fin:
        if line.rstrip() == "*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE KAMA SUTRA OF VATSYAYANA ***":
            break

    for line in fin:
        process_line(line, h)

    return h
print(filename)
```

So I started with the above code, but only got the filename displayed as output. How do I rewrite my code to answer this question appropriately?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is too broad for this forum.  You seem to want someone to write the code for you, or at least to give you a step by step tutorial on how to accomplish the problem.  Neither of these is an appropriate question for SO.  You need to give more effort to arriving at a solution and then ask more specific questions when you run into problems.  Please check out [THIS POST](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: Step 1: you need to actually call the `process_file` function.

Comment: Whatever is returned by `process_line` is never assigned to a variable. It's kind of like writing `1 + 1` instead of `x = 1 + 1`. Both calculate `1 + 1` but only the latter stores the result.

Comment: Nothing is returned by `process_file`, because as @ThePhoton points out, that function is never being called.  So it's more like writing `<nothing>` rather than writing `x = 1 + 1`.